# Is a there a way to use list comprehension to count the frequency of grouped by elements for a certain condition but not for other elements?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to group the elements in a list to condense it and keep it in the same order, but only if it meets certain conditions.

Say I have a list, and I condense it using this list comprehension:

```
>> l = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,"7","7","7",5,5]
>> [len(list(group)) if not isinstance(key, str) else key for key, group in groupby(l)]
```

Output:

```
>> [2, 2, 2, 3, '7', 2]
```

Desired output:

```
>> [2, 2, 2, 3, '7', '7', '7', 2]
```

So I only want the frequency of the element if it is a number, but if it is a string, I want every single occurrence listed instead of only once.

I understand its because the comprehension is using "groupby(l)" instead of "l" to create the new list, but what alternative do I have?

Answer (score 2):

Using a generator expression with [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

L = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,"7","7","7",5,5]

gen = ([len(list(g))] if not isinstance(k, str) else list(g) for k, g in groupby(L))
res = list(chain.from_iterable(gen))
# [2, 2, 2, 3, '7', '7', '7', 2]
```

Cleaner, in my opinion, is defining a function for this:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

def func(args):
    key, grp = args
    lst = list(grp)
    if not isinstance(key, str):
        yield len(lst)
    else:
        yield from lst

res = list(chain.from_iterable(map(func, groupby(L))))
# [2, 2, 2, 3, '7', '7', '7', 2]
```

Comment: I agree with you, second option much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Not using list comprehension

```
from itertools import groupby
l = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,"7","7","7",5,5]
out=[]
for key, group in groupby(l):
    if not isinstance(key, str):
        out.append(len(list(group)))
    else:
        out.extend(list(group))
```

Output `[2, 2, 2, 3, '7', '7', '7', 2]`

Comment: Why `out.extend(key*len(list(group)))` and not `out.extend(list(group))`?

Comment: @SuperShoot I knew I was overdoing something. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension to iterate over the grouped items individually if the key is a string:

```
from itertools import groupby
[i for k, g in groupby(l) for i in (list(g) if isinstance(k, str) else (len(list(g)),))]
```

This returns:

```
[2, 2, 2, 3, '7', '7', '7', 2]
```